# Adding elements to DOM with different coordinates each time

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a to-do list and I have a constructor function for creating the list items. Each time the user hits enter in the input field I want a new task element to be created just below the first one. As of now, I've tried several methods: looping through the constructor function and looping through the individual command that gives the position of the element within the constructor function.

```js
let addTask = document.getElementById('addItem');
addTask.value = '';
let items = [];
let taskBG;
let taskText;

function Task(){
        taskBG = document.createElement('div');
        taskBG.style.height = '60px';
        taskBG.style.width = '800px';
        taskBG.style.marginTop = '-680px';
        taskBG.style.marginLeft = '502px';
        taskBG.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        taskText = document.createElement('div');
        taskText.style.position = 'absolute';
        taskText.style.marginTop = '-680px';
        taskText.style.marginLeft = '550px';
        taskText.style.fontSize = '50px';
        taskText.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
        taskText.style.color = 'lightgrey';
        taskBG.appendChild(taskText);
        document.body.appendChild(taskText);
        document.body.appendChild(taskBG);
};

addTask.addEventListener('keydown', (ev) => {
    if(ev.keyCode == 13){
        items.push(addTask.value);
        new Task();
        addTask.value = '';
        for(let i=0; i < items.length; i++){
            taskText.textContent = items[i];
        };
    };
});
```

```css
body {
    background-image:url(backg.jpg);
    background-size:2400px, 2400px;
}

#mainBG {
    height:900px;
    width:900px;
    background-color:rgb(72, 73, 73);
    opacity:0.6;
    display:grid;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#mainTitle {
    display:grid;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:100px;
    width:700px;
    background-color:black;
    border-radius:10px;
}

#mainText {
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    display:grid;
    margin:0 auto;
    font-size:70px;
    font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
}

#addItem {
    display:grid;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:30px;
    width:400px;
    margin-top:-360px;
    border-radius:10px;
    background-color:rgb(128, 201, 201);
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> To-Do </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mainBG">
            <div id="mainTitle">
                <div id="mainText">To-Do</div>
            </div>
            <input id="addItem" type="text" placeholder="Add a Task!">
        </div>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
let addTask = document.getElementById('addItem');
addTask.value = '';
let items = [];
let taskBG;
let taskText;
var totalTasks = 0;

function Task(){
    taskBG = document.createElement('div');
    taskBG.style.height = '60px';
    taskBG.style.width = '800px';
    if (totalTasks == 0) {
        taskBG.style.marginTop = '-680px';
    }
    taskBG.style.marginLeft = '502px';
    taskBG.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    taskText = document.createElement('div');
    taskText.style.position = 'absolute';
    if (totalTasks == 0) {
        taskText.style.marginTop = '-680px';
    }
    taskText.style.marginLeft = '550px';
    taskText.style.fontSize = '50px';
    taskText.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
    taskText.style.color = 'lightgrey';
    taskBG.appendChild(taskText);
    document.body.appendChild(taskText);
    document.body.appendChild(taskBG);
    if (totalTasks == 0) {
      totalTasks = 1;
    }
};

addTask.addEventListener('keydown', (ev) => {
    if(ev.keyCode == 13){
        items.push(addTask.value);
        new Task();
        addTask.value = '';
        for(let i=0; i < items.length; i++){
            taskText.textContent = items[i];
        };
    };
});
```

```css
body {
    background-image:url(backg.jpg);
    background-size:2400px, 2400px;
}

#mainBG {
    height:900px;
    width:900px;
    background-color:rgb(72, 73, 73);
    opacity:0.6;
    display:grid;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#mainTitle {
    display:grid;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:100px;
    width:700px;
    background-color:black;
    border-radius:10px;
}

#mainText {
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    display:grid;
    margin:0 auto;
    font-size:70px;
    font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
}

#addItem {
    display:grid;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:30px;
    width:400px;
    margin-top:-360px;
    border-radius:10px;
    background-color:rgb(128, 201, 201);
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> To-Do </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mainBG">
            <div id="mainTitle">
                <div id="mainText">To-Do</div>
            </div>
            <input id="addItem" type="text" placeholder="Add a Task!">
        </div>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have just added `totalTasks` var with the value of `0` and in `task()` function I am checking if the variable is `0` then add `marginTop` otherwise do not add it. As   `marginTop` only needed in the first task for the remaining it doesn't be needed.